# Storing a hash in batches

Tags: sql, perl

I'm trying to retrieve a bunch of rows using sql (as a test - lets say 1000 rows in each iteration up to a million rows) and store in a file (.store file in my case but could be a text file - doesn't matter) in batches to avoid an out of memory issue. I am  sql within a perl script.

Will appreciate if anyone can share an example.

example would be like -

```
sub query{

 $test = "select * from employees";
return $test;  
}

// later in the code - 

my $temp;
my $dataset=DBUtils::make_database_iterator({query=> test($temp)});
            }
     store $dataset, $result_file;
        return;
```

Comment: What is a .store file?
What do you mean by "calling sql"? Perhaps show some code.

Comment: Your question is overly brief and gives very little useable information. What is this *hash* thet you mention in the title? Are you sure you don't need just another SQL table?

Comment: Are you asking if you have to "preallocate" the size the hash?  *e.g.* `keys(%yourhash) = 1024; # num of keys always a power of 2`  I'm not sure how much faster this would make things on a modern machine but I guess it could help you kee memory use more predicable?

Comment: Are you using Perl DBI (Database Interface)?  Which database driver (DBD) module? What is the code you're using?

Comment: i edited my question and put the sample. Thanks for the helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

The best I can offer you with the limited amount of information you have given is this, which uses the `SELECT` statement's `LIMIT` clause to retrieve a limited number of rows from the table.

Obviously you will have to provide actual values for the DSN, the name of the table, and the `store_block` subroutine yourself.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use DBI;

my $blocksize = 1000;
my ($dsn, $user, $pass) = (...);

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ? OFFSET ?') or die $DBI::errstr;
open my $fh, '>', 'test.store';

for (my $n = 0; $sth->execute($blocksize, $n * $blocksize); ++$n) {
  my $block = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
  last unless @$block;
  store_block($block, $fh);
}

close $fh;

sub store_block {
  my ($block, $fh) = @_;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thank you for assistance and providing example.. 

I don't want to put the limit over the query, rather break the result set for rows in sets of 1000 rows and then store, then get the next thousand and store.. and repeat.

I see the logic of  -

for (my $n = 0; $sth->execute($blocksize, $n * $blocksize); ++$n) {
  my $block = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
  last unless @$block;
  store_block($block, $fh);

will this do the job without putting the limit? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @mohitverma09: The SQL statement `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT n OFFSET f` selects `n` rows, ignoring the first `f` rows in the table. The `prepare` uses placeholders for these parameters, and the real values are provided in the `execute` call, so the program selects `$blocksize` rows, ignoring the first `$n * $blocksize` rows in the table. Then `fetchall_arrayref` retrieves all the data in the selected rows. If `fetchall_arrayref` returns a reference to an empty array then the specified offset is off the end of the table and all the blocks have been fetched. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @mohitverma09: Why do you say, *"I don't want to put the limit over the query"*? And what do you mean by, *"will this do the job without putting the limit"*? If you don't use a `LIMIT` clause then you can use `fetchrow_arrayref` to fetch the selected rows one-by-one, but DBI will have retrieved *all the the rows* immediately and will just pass them to you one at a time, so you will probably still have memory problems.

Comment: Hey Borodin, my bad.. i got the idea and applied it to my program,. Thank you very much for the assistance.. 

I'm at this point and facing hurdles here - I got to a point where i could throw the data into pages by the offset scheme but now i'm trying to append to the file. Hopefully, I will be able to get through this issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to work in batches to avoid an out of memory error.  This suggests you're doing something like this...

```
my @all_the_rows = query_the_database($sql);
store_stuff(@all_the_rows);
```

You want to avoid doing that as much as possible for exactly the reason you gave, if the dataset grows large you might run out of memory.

Instead, you can read one row at a time and write one row at a time using [DBI](http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# The file you're writing results to
my $file = '...';

# Connect to the database using DBI
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    ...however you do that...,
    {RaiseError => 1}    # Turn on exceptions
);

# Prepare and execute the statement
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees");
$sth->execute;

# Get a row, write a row.
while( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    append_row_to_storage($row, $file);
}
```

I leave writing `append_row_to_storage` up to you.